# Programatically add and remove servers under IIS 10 / ARR 3 now that WFF is deprecated?

Tags: iis

We are migrating to IIS 10 / ARR 3.

In IIS 7.5 we were able to leverage the WebFarmSnapIn to add / remove servers from the web farm programatically via Powershell.

WFF is now deprecated it seems. How can we do this? It doesn't seem to be supported by the standard IIS cmdlets.